# I have visual studio 2010 installed, what else do I need for windows phone 7 development?

Tags: silverlight, development-environment, expression-blend, windows-phone-7

I have VS2010 and Expression studio 4 on my machine. I have done a fair amount of programming on Silverlight. What do I need to get started with development on Windows phone 7. I googled and found out that I need to install VS2010 express for WP7 beta. Can't I just use my existing VS2010 installation with some additional templates and an WP7 emulator? And Is it possible to use blend? Is there anything else required to set up dev environment for wp7
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and install the [Windows Phone Developer Tools Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c8496c2a-54d9-4b11-9491-a1bfaf32f2e3) and you are ready to go.

Comment: I am aware of Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone Beta (as mentioned in my question)

Comment: @P.K. The tools will also update an existing instance of Visual Studio and Blen 4, you do not need to use the installed Visual Studio express.

Comment: that's right - as per the release notes: "If you have Visual Studio 2010 Professional or a higher edition installed, continue to use it for Windows Phone development."

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have VS2010 Pro or higher version installed, you still need to install WP Developer Tools .. This will install the templates for WP development in VS 2010 Pro/ultimate for development of WP7 apps. Also Expression Blend for Windows Phone is different from Expression Studio